# Unable to set colors in PHPUnit using phpunit.xml

Tags: php, testing, phpunit

I am trying to set/enable colors for PHPUnit using phpunit.xml configuration on windows 10 command prompt. But for some funny wierd reasons it doesn't seem to work. Here is what i have tried so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<phpunit
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://schema.phpunit.de/|version|/phpunit.xsd"
  columns="max"
  colors="true"
  bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
  verbose="true"
  stopOnFailure="false"
  stopOnError="false"
  stopOnRisky="false"
  stopOnWarning="false"
  stopOnIncomplete="false"
>
  <testsuites>
    ...
  </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

Also it worked when i set it through the command argument like so

```
.\vendor\bin\phpunit --colors=always
```

But i want to set through the xml for convenience reasons. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you're loading the correct xml?

Comment: @DanBizdadea yeah i am

Comment: that |version| in the xml is replaced with actual version? It may cause parsing errors not finding the xsd file.

Comment: Which phpunit version are you using?

Comment: @RobbieAverill version 7

Comment: Did you replace `|version|` with your version? The example on the website is a template

Comment: @RobbieAverill yeah i have tried that ; “https://schema.phpunit.de/|7.3.1|/phpunit.xsd— but it didn’t work

Comment: Remove the `|` symbols

Comment: @ Robbie Averill i have removed the pipes '|', but it's not still working